# serialize() returns empty after ajax html

Tags: jquery, serialization, find

I am trying to rebind a click event to post a form and ajax the html

```
$('.btnSave').addClass('yui3-button').click(function() {
    var $this =  $(this);
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    $.post(
        "MTrades/save", 
        $.param({ mycase: 1 }) + '&' + $(this).parent().parent().serialize(),
        function(data) {
            alert("page - " + data);
            $this.parent().fadeOut("fast").load(
                "MTrades/index/"+id+"/options", 
                function() {
                    //rebind the click event
                    BindClick();
                }).fadeIn("fast");
            });
            return false;
        });
```

The form parameters send works for the first time but not the second time 
(after I have saved and reloaded the html)
the .serialize() returns empty.

html (shorten):

```
<form id="Form2">
    <button>
    <div>
        <button>save
        <form>
            <table>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean with reloaded? Form's inside forms won't work.

Comment: In your html you have a `form` within a `form` (which is invalid) which one is actually being submit?

Comment: if i'll change the outer form to a div, how do I get to the inner one from the save btn? is it `$(this).parent().find('form').serialize()` is there a more elegant way to look for the inner form?

Comment: The button tags are not closed.

Comment: yes I know, it was just a markup. thank you. The problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the outer form with `<div>`
and I send the inner `<form>` with `$(this).parent().find('form').serialize()`
instead of `$(this).parent().parent().serialize()`